# android - how to check bluetooth baudrate in adb shell

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I remember there is a place to check the baudrate in Android system.

However, I dont exactly remember where it is.

In adb shell, there should be a directory to find out.

Can anyone let me know this information? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call the following on command windows

am startservice -a com.company.service.bluetooth.ON

Try this it will work..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I remember there is a file which I can "cat" to see what baudrate is in system.